# I there anyway to have multiple colors in a SwiftUI TextEditor text?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

I am using a SwiftUI TextEditor and would like to change the color of characters from when user has typed in a certain number of characters.  Is there any way to achieve this?

So there will be two colors in the TextEditor.  First 140 characters will be black and next characters all red in example below.  I am also okay with Black and Blue if there is anyway to cheat and use link color.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var text: String = "" {
        didSet {
            if text.count > 140 {
                // replace text with text that has first 140 characters black color and remaining red color.
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $viewModel.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: look-up `AttributedString` to change string attributes such as color.

Comment: Attributed text cannot be used in a texteditor as far as I know.

Comment: ok, my mistake.

Comment: same mistake I made, the link refers to `Text` not `TextEditor`.

Comment: I am afraid `TextEditor` could not do what you want.

Try to bridge `UITextView` from UIKit.